# scrolling the nav bar depending on mouse position is not smooth need improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smoothing

> i'm trying to move the nav bar depending on the mouse position which works but i cant make smooth when i move the mouse to a point then stop ,the margin top is taking too long to update the new values. which makes it look like jittring instead of smooth animation

```
function nav_animate(e) {
var mouse_y = e.pageY;
if (mouse_y < 200) {

var old_y = $("#nav-style").css('margin-top').replace('px', '');
var new_y = parseInt(old_y);
var tmp = -(mouse_y + new_y); 
if (tmp > 0) {
  tmp = 0;
}
$("#nav-style").css({ 'margin-top': tmp + 'px' });
}else {
   $("#nav-style").css({ 'margin-top': '-101px' });
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('mousemove', nav_animate);
});
```

> since i didn't  present my problem well here is a link to the site im doing [here](https://michaport.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: use `translateX` CSS transform instead of modifying the margin. Cf [Achieving 60 FPS Animations with CSS3](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108)

Comment: Is it page going to be scrolling to a particular `div` in the page?

Comment: no its just the nav bar dropping down the closer the mouse come up

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the power of CSS?

Here's a simple example:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* Change the link color on hover */
    li a:hover {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>
    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```